# How to work with Liquid variables in Java file Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need the value of the liquid variable `{{ section.settings.product_count }}` in my **theme.js.liquid** file.

I am new to liquid so I tried many things that I saw online. None of them worked.

Things I tried that didn’t work:

```js
{%- assign limit = section.settings.product_count -%}

console.log({{ limit }});
```

```js
var limit = "{{section.settings.product_count}}"
console.log(limit);
```

Comment: good luck getting answers.  Instead of commenting on what I answered on your previous question (so that I can make it clear), you chose to just create a new one, with the exact content.

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to make the problem clearer. I feel that my other question was not so clear. I am new to this platform sry